# Light baking from sunlight not turning out like render

Tags: baking

I've started to play with blender and try to bake sunlight but for some reason, it doesn't turn like the rendered even though the model is pretty basic

[Blender model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l1YK32qTyjp94kztOVSPN5_B1FwGZGmK/view?usp=sharing)

**Bake config**

[image: bake config]

**Without baking**
[image: without baking]

**With baking**
[image: baked light]

Comment: I'm on tablet so I can't check your blend at the moment, but inspect double faces or face normal direction ...

Comment: I had double faces but removing them did not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a several issues, but mainly it is a topology problem of disconnected edges (if you drag vertex aside you can see it is not a single face ...

[image]

... if you delete side faces (left/right from window) select edges around and fill by face issue is fixed.

[image]

Since you generate a new faces to fix the model you would have to unwrap again (if you are using Bake with margin, be sure you also unwrap with some margin (otherwise bake will penetrate martino surrounded faces.)

There were other problems - switched face normal, and 4 doubles, but it was fixed by previous adjustments.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way I can find it myself next time? And is there any video for building correct models

Comment: Next time ... like now when you see this weird shading. How to build properly? You could use Boolean operator (or modifier) or Extrude+Scale and Extrude  to move out for wall thickness (or instead second extrude use Solidify modifier (it depends on model case.